# Gcc won't recognise an Ada with'd unit

Tags: ada

I am trying to compile an Ada unit that withs specifications declared with three level package names such as package A.B.C but the compilation fails complaining that there is no unit A.B
That is it seems only to search for files named A-B.ads and not for A-B-C.ads.
How do I get gcc to look for the correct file?
Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`with A.B.C;` implies `with` of both `A` and `A.B`, as well as `A.B.C`.
So it does look for the correct file, but it needs the other two as well.
Make sure all dependencies are available in your search path(s).

Also, make sure your filenames are in lower case (`a.ads`, `a-b.ads`, `a-b-c.ads`) as that's what GNAT/gcc expects.

Answer (score 1):

The dot operator has a special meaning of a relationship between Ada packages. `with A.B.C` means that package C is a child of package B and B is a child of package A. This implies that if there is no parent package, the child package cannot be used either. In other words, to allow the `with` statement on a child package, there must exist a parent package, although it can be empty. Thus, you need to create packages A an B like as follows:

```
-- Spec
package A is
   -- Empty spec
end A;

-- Spec
package A.B is
   -- Empty spec
end B;

-- Spec
package A.B.C is
-- Definitions of package C
end C;
```

Note that if a spec does not have procedures, it is not allowed to add a package body. Note also that whether `with A.B.C` implies `with A` and `with A.B` depends on the configuration of the run-time system.

Comment: You can have an otherwise-forbidden package body if you add `pragma Elaborate_Body;` (or the corresponding [aspect](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-K-1.html#p22)) to the spec. And, I don’t believe the RTS configuration has anything to do with whether `with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;` implies that `Ada.Strings` is visible (it is).